# When cursor hit an model it shows Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined

Tags: aframe

I'm new to a-frame, so if the question is really easy please be patient with it. My question is that when a cursor hit an model it shows Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined.Here is my code:

```
<a-scene>
  <a-assets>
    <img id="room" src="./pics/room.jpg">
    <a-asset-item id="crate-obj" src="/models/chair/Chair.obj"></a-asset-item>
    <a-asset-item id="crate-mtl" src="/models/chair/Chair.mtl"></a-asset-item>
  </a-assets>

  <a-entity position="0 1.8 4">
    <a-camera id="camera">
      <a-cursor id="cursor" color="#4CC3D9"></a-cursor>
    </a-camera>
  </a-entity>
  <a-obj-model src="#crate-obj" mtl="#crate-mtl"></a-obj-model>
  <a-sky src="#room"></a-sky>
</a-scene>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this link.[aframe issue](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/692).The author said that we can workaround  to create an transparent bounding box and listen for click events on that.

Comment: This answer would have been great if you added that workaround using the markup from the OP.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been fixed at https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/pull/1497 by binding the A-Frame entity to each child of the model.

You can wait for A-Frame 0.3.0 or use the latest A-Frame master. Right now, the `cursor` uses a `raycaster` to see what object was intersected. With OBJ/COLLADA models, it creates a tree of objects. However, A-Frame was only treating the top-level object as an entity. So when the raycaster returned the object, it did not have an associated entity to emit an event with.

Now it should just work:

```
<a-camera><a-cursor></a-cursor></a-camera>
<a-obj-model></a-obj-model>
```

Comment: That is great, can you maybe elaborate a bit with a code example to prevent that we flag this as spam (what is currently happening)?